# Custom Annotation with AspectJ capture parameters

Tags: java, parameters, annotations, aop, aspectj

**Custom annotation with AspectJ**

**Custom Annotation**

```
@Documented
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Inherited
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Loggable {

String getString() default "";
boolean print() default true;

}
```

**Aspect**

```
@Before("execution(@Loggable  * *.*(..))")
public void myBeforeAdvice(JoinPoint jp) {

    System.out.println("Before List");

    Object[] parameterList = jp.getArgs();

    System.out.println("Length=="+ parameterList.length);

    System.out.println("After List");

    //return returnVal;
}
```

**Custom Annotation Use**

```
@Loggable(getString="Custom", print=true)
public String run(){

    System.out.println("Inside Run Method");

    return "Returning Method Run!";
}
```

`OutPut`

`Before List`

`Length==0`

`After List`

`Inside Run Method`

How Can I get Parameter of Custom Annotation, because I take some decision base on parameter ! `i.e print may be true / false`

Update me !

Answer (score 1):

`before(Loggable l) : call(@Loggable * *.*(..)) && @annotation(l);`

think its similar for the annotation based pointcuts.